# procedure return True or False

Tags: firebird, firebird-3.0, firebird-psql

I need a stored procedure in firebird 3.0 to return True, False or 1,0 result
to check if this person or the record exists in database. If exists the procedure should return true, if not return False, or return 1, if not return 0

This is my procedure but it gives me an error:
[image: https://i.ibb.co/HLZQY59/Capture.jpg]

> Invalid token.
> Dynamic SQL Error.
> SQL error code = -104
> Token unknown - line 10, column 1.
> end.

I want to check if the record is exist or not by checking the first name last name and day of birth.

```
create procedure aa(
v varchar(20),
g varchar(20),
dd date)
as 
begin
select fname,lname,bday from STUDENT
where not exists (select fname,lname,bday from STUDENT  where fname=:v and lname=:g and bday=:dd)
end
```

Comment: Also, explain exactly what you are trying to achieve (eg under what conditions should it return true?), because besides its obvious syntax errors, this procedure doesn't attempt in any way to return a boolean value, so it is not really obvious how to fix this procedure beyond fixing the syntax errors.

Comment: I want to check if this record is exist or not check it with the first naame LastName Day of birth

Comment: And the error you get? And please add details in an [edit] to your question. Don't add them in the comments.

Comment: i edited my question post 
the database do not save my procedure
what i i want is check if this person or the record exist in database

Comment: Do you have programming experience in classic imperative languages (C, Java, Pascal, Basic) ? Problem is, your code does not have a specific error, it just has no sense... Like few random commands copy-pasted from random places without understanding how and why they even do work. You may read the `Procedural SQL` chapter of the docs - but it assumes you have a basic understanding of imperative languages programming and it adapts your generic skills to PSQL specifics, but if you don't have those it will not help you.

Comment: The docs: http://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-psql ~~~ your procedure does not have any output parameters, so it can not "return" no any value ~~~ outer `select` in your proc has nowhere to save the results to ~~~ would your outer `select` return less than one row or more than one row - there is no handling for it. /// Those gaps are obvious but taken together... Even making some code, that does not crash with error s, would not mean it returns correct, expected data in all cases

Comment: i add a return variable but the same problem
create procedure aa(                                                                                                           
v varchar(20),
g varchar(20),
dd date)
returns
(aa integer)as 
begin
select fname,lname,bday from STUDENT
where not exists (select fname,lname,bday from STUDENT  where fname=:v and lname=:g and bday=:dd)
end

Comment: the samecreate procedure aa(
v varchar(20),
g varchar(20),
dd date)
returns
(result boolean)
as 
begin
result=(select fname,lfname,bday from STUDENT
where not exists (select fname,lname,bday from STUDENT  where fname=:v and lfname=:g and bday=:dd));
end;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stored procedure doesn't work because 1) it doesn't have a [`RETURNS` clause](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html#fblangref30-ddl-proc-params) so it cannot return true or false, and 2) a select in PSQL requires an [`INTO` clause](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html#fblangref30-dml-select-into) to put the values into a variable or return-parameter.

Based on your code, a stored procedure that does what you want would be:

```sql
create procedure aa(
  v varchar(20),
  g varchar(20),
  dd date)
  returns (student_exists boolean)
as 
begin
  student_exists = exists (select * from STUDENT where fname=:v and lname=:g and bday=:dd);
end
```

Depending on what you're need to achieve, a [function](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html#fblangref30-psql-storedfuncs) might be more appropriate:

```sql
create function aa(
  v varchar(20),
  g varchar(20),
  dd date)
  returns boolean
as 
begin
  return exists (select * from STUDENT where fname=:v and lname=:g and bday=:dd);
end
```